# Why does a try catch still throw an error in C#?

Tags: c#

Why this code still throw exception to me?

```
foreach (HtmlNode infoNode in infoNodes)
{
  try
  {
    content = infoNode.SelectSingleNode("td/span/a").InnerText;
    result.Add("releasedate", content);
  }catch{ continue;}
}
```

Comment: it should not. and you dont need the `continue`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: If you don't want to know the exception message and don't want to be at any moment stucked on catch just remove it, and the execution will continue.

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem possible to throw any exception within the try-catch block, given the code in the question, but notice that the `foreach` head is not surrounded by a try-catch block.

```
foreach(var a in b)
{
    statements...
}
```

is a syntax sugar for

```
1   var enumerator = b.GetEnumerator();
2   while(enumerator.MoveNext())
3   {
4       var a = enumerator.Current;
5       statements...
6   }
```

Notice that line 1, 2, and 4 are still operations that could throw exceptions that are not caught.

Comment: Note that code _can_ throw an exception from inside the `catch` part of a try/catch. But I agree with your point here.

Comment: @NateBarbettini I have updated the answer to limit it to the given condition, thank you.